# How to SSL enable SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, ssl

What is the best way to SSL enable a SharePoint farm? I'm thinking ISA, but so far I'm having issues with document libraries and other erratic things.

Can anyone describe a checklist or some best practices in enabling SSL on a SharePoint farm?

Comment: You might get more information about this on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Configuring SSL in SharePoint 2007 development environment](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/configuring-ssl-in-sharepoint-2007-development-environment/)